# Can't install package because of Old Command in Setup.Py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to use pip to install a package but get the following error output. I'm aware that decode is no longer used in Python 3.x (I'm using 3.6) and am not sure how to get the file to install.

> C:\Users\sgand>pip install housecanary
>   Collecting housecanary
>
> Using cached housecanary-0.6.5.tar.gz

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sgand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u0ymg1zl\housecanary\setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    version=find_version('housecanary', '__init__.py'),
  File "C:\Users\sgand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u0ymg1zl\housecanary\setup.py", line 13, in find_version
    version_file = read(*file_paths)
  File "C:\Users\sgand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u0ymg1zl\housecanary\setup.py", line 9, in read
    return codecs.open(os.path.join(*parts), 'r').read().decode('UTF-8')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem when I try it on different versions of Python 3, like

```
docker run python:3.2 pip install housecanary
```

or

```
docker run python:3.6 pip install housecanary
```

It's pretty clear to me that Housecanary is not compatible with Python 3.

So either you find another library to use, or you downgrade the Python 2 -- which I really wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You're a computer programmer, fix it. Download and unpack the package, edit the `setup.py` to be correct, run `python setup.py build && python setup.py install`, and enjoy -- or move on to the next problem, since a failure to install on Python 3 indicates a lack of testing on that platform, and probably other issues hiding under the surface. If you do get it working, you can always send a patch to the maintainer and see if it is accepted.